# gRPC and XAMPP not working

Tags: php, xampp, grpc

For a project I want to test the new database from Firebase, Firestore with PHP. But before i can use it, I need a couple of tools. I am trying for a day now to get it work, but no success.
I'm stuck on gRPC. I installed is, and it's working on my Mac and I can install Firestore with Composer, but I can't get it to work with XAMPP. 
When I load a page I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\GoogleException: The requested client requires the gRPC extension. 
>   Please see https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for installation instructions. in /vendor/google/cloud-core/src/ClientTrait.php:75 Stack trace: #0 /vendor/google/cloud-firestore/src/FirestoreClient.php(115): Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient->requireGrpc() #1 /app/firebase.php(18): Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient->__construct() #2 /app/firebase.php(21): App\initialize() #3 /template.php(688): require_once('/Applications/X...') #4 /template.php(647): load_template('/Applications/X...', true) #5 /App in /vendor/google/cloud-core/src/ClientTrait.php on line 75

I added extension=grpc.so to the php.ini that is loaded by XAMPP.
But no success.

Comment: have you checked `phpinfo();` to see if you see if the lib is loading and enabled?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, please if you found the solution write it.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DLL file, download from here https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC

Answer (score 0):

Open your `php.ini` file and uncomment the line `extension_dir="ext"`,
add `extension="grpc"`.
Then go to the environment variables in the properties, choose path in the system variables and add the php path you are using.
I am using `C:\xampp\php` that's where all the magic will happen it's been a tag of war.